# How can I cache RequestFactory data on client side?

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

Is there a part of `RequestFactory` classes I can override to provide automatic caching for some requests?  I could cache outside RF, of course, but I'd like to do it via overriding to be totally invisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ServiceLayer.invoke()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/requestfactory/server/ServiceLayerDecorator.html#invoke%28java.lang.reflect.Method,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method could be patched via the `ServiceLayerDecorator` chain.  It's called from `SimpleRequestProcessor.processInvocationMessages()` after all of the [OperationMessages](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/requestfactory/shared/messages/OperationMessage.html) have been applied.

Comment: I have the same requirements but these classes are server side classes and I can't see how this helps. How would you go about caching on the client side?